# Override currency format / monetary display

Tags: contributions

Is it possible somehow to override the CiviCRM's ISO-standard based currency formatting settings?

My site uses "hu_HU" as default setting, but I'd like to remove all decimals (instead of having two decimal digits), if it's possible site-wide (on pages, in lists and in messages, too).

I use Drupal 7.99 with CiviCRM 5.68 on PHP 8.1.

Thanks!